# Cropping ImageView to Produce a New Image

Tags: ios

I am trying to crop an Image whenever the user touches the UIImageView on the screen. The UIImageView is 640 X 300 area and I allow user to touch anywhere in the UIImageView. Then I use the following code to view the croppedImage and it always show me the wrong image. I think I am having trouble getting the correct coordinates.

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    UIImage *originalImage = self.imageView.image;

    NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f",location.x,location.y);

    CGRect cropRegion = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 10, 10);

    CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, cropRegion);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the coordinates relative to self.view, not relative to the image view.  Try:

```
CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.imageView];
```

Comment: Thanks I even tried the self.imageView but still got the same result. For some reason it feels that the y-axis is messed up. The UIImageView covers half the screen not full screen.